# PHP How to convert each element of array to timestamp?

Tags: php, arrays, strtotime, timestamp, array-map

I have a two-element array - $time

echo var_dump($time) :

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'otw' => string '12:00' (length=5)
      'zam' => string '15:00' (length=5)
 1 => 
    array
      'otw' => string '16:00' (length=5)
      'zam' => string '18:00' (length=5)
```

How convert each element of $time array to timestamp?

echo var_dump($time) should look like:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'otw' => timestamp 'timestampvalue' (length=)
      'zam' => timestamp 'timestampvalue' (length=)
 1 => 
    array
      'otw' => timestamp 'timestampvalue' (length=)
      'zam' => timestamp 'timestampvalue' (length=)
```

Comment: Have a look at array_walk_recursive()

Comment: You're not expecting us to code a solution for you, are you? Maybe take a good look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 4):

simply use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive)

```
array_walk_recursive($your_array, function(&$element) {
  // notice: this will use the date of today and add the time to it.
  $element = strtotime($element);
  // $element = strtotime($element, 0); // use 1.1.1970 as current date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using array_map()

```
function arrayToTimestamps($array)
{
    return array(strtotime($array['otw']), strtotime($array['zam']));
}
$newArray = array_map('arrayToTimestamps', $array);
```

Comment: this does not work, because `array_walk_recursive` tries to pass an second argument

Comment: Yes, the whole thing was wrong, this is what I meant though.